# Why can't sed replace 0x24 byte in binary file?

Tags: replace, sed, binary, hex, binaryfiles

I'm want to replace some bytes in binary file to another.
Created sample (6 bytes long) file via

```
echo -ne '\x8f\x15\x42\x02\x24\xc2' > test
```

Then tried to replace bytes **\x15\x42\x02** to **\x12\x12\x02** via sed:

```
sed 's \x15\x42\x02 \x12\x12\x02 g' test > test1
```

sed replaced bytes:

```
cat test test1 | xxd -c 6
0000000: 8f15 4202 24c2  ..B.$.
0000006: 8f12 1202 24c2  ....$.
           ^^ ^^^^
```

Tried then replace bytes **\x42\x02\x24** to **\x12\x02\x24**:

```
sed 's \x42\x02\x24 \x12\x02\x24 g' test > test2
```

sed NOT replaced bytes:

```
cat test test2 | xxd -c 6
0000000: 8f15 4202 24c2  ..B.$.
0000006: 8f15 4202 24c2  ..B.$.
              ^^^^ ^^
```

What's wrong? I have sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2 (Kubuntu 13.10)

Thank You.

Comment: I wonder if it is because \x24 is `$` which is a regex-special char (line anchor), and the sequence `\x42\x02` does not occur at the end-of-line

Comment: I've experimented with it a bit, with various substitutions of various lengths, and I think Glenn is right.

Comment: Anyhow, `sed` is not meant for binary substitutions. You'll run into problems with multibyte characters and so on. Better use [bbe](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bbe) for that, some kind of "`sed` for binaries"

Answer (score 9):

It is because `0x24` is the hex code for the `$` character.  Note that `^` and `$` have special meaning in regex (which `sed` uses for matching), and literally means "at the beginning of the line", and "at the end of the line", respectively.  As such, those characters are ignored unless escaped.  Therefore,

`echo "this and that" | sed 's/this$/cat/'`

will leave the string unchanged because it you're telling sed to look for 'this' at the end of the line -- since 'that' is at the end, it doesn't match.  However,

`echo "It costs $50.00." | sed 's/\$50\.00/47.00 Swiss Francs/'`

Will change the line as expected because the `$` was escaped.  For binary data, just include the hex code for the `\` character (`\x5c`) just prior to `\x24` in the regex section, and it should work just fine.

Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this,

```
hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2X"' file1 | sed 's/420224/121224/g' | xxd -r -p > new_updated
```

**Test:**

```
sat:~# xxd -c 6  file1
0000000: 8f15 4202 24c2  ..B.$.
sat:~# hexdump -ve '1/1 "%.2X"' file1 | sed 's/420224/121224/g' | xxd -r -p > new_updated
sat:~# xxd -c 6 new_updated
0000000: 8f15 1212 24c2  ....$.
```

Comment: Thank You, but I'm interested, why sed can replace ceritain sequence of bytes bytes, and can't replace another sequence of bytes definetely presented in file. There is no place to mistake - I'd directly copy-pasted bytes from echo command to sed command.

Answer (score 1):

the sed statement should be like below

```
sed 's/\x15\x42\x02/\x12\x12\x02/g' test > test1
```

their should be / between the search pattern and the pattern that should replace it

and the result should be like below

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat test test1 | xxd -c 6       
0000000: 8f15 4202 24c2  ..B.$.
0000006: 8f12 1202 24c2  ....$.
```

Comment: It works with / just like witn space as command/regex delimiter - still replacing \x15\x42\x02, but not replacing \x42\x02\x24

Comment: it works but you need to pass 8 instead of 6 to xdd check it out and confirm

Comment: sed 's/\x42\x02\x24/\x12\x02\x24/g' test > test4 ; md5sum test test4 
d1c66101d794687bf5d61b5ae4b7da03  test 
d1c66101d794687bf5d61b5ae4b7da03  test4 - no luck, xxd is just to visualize changes

Comment: What OS do You using? I'm using Kubuntu 13.10 AMD64, md5sum of /bin/sed is 081c50c87d36bd90dadfb4df9483cacd. http://pastebin.com/wAMji5g7